# Prevent HTML 5 Video from downloading the whole file at once

Tags: html, video, streaming

I wonder if its possible to download just the first 5 chunks (5MB) of a html5 video and so prevent to have high traffic bills when showing videos >100MB

Comment: Does it actually download the whole video if a user moves away from the page where you have your video before the whole thing is downloaded? (I'm guessing you want the user to be able to view the whole video but if it moves away from the page it should stop, right?)

Comment: thanks for asking...yes indeed! But the thing is....i want to optimize it...as statistics show users leave the page within 30 seconds or so...so no need to load the whole vid

Answer (score 0):

the only way to have some control over this is with the preload attribute on the video tag. Sadly this is implemented differently in different browsers (eg `auto` may download 2s, 25s or the whole video depending on the connection).

Solutions like FMS or IIS SmoothStreaming allow more control, but require plugins (Flash or Silverlight) to manage that experience

```
preload='none'
From the spec, “Hints to the UA that the user is not expected to need the video, or that     minimizing unnecessary traffic is desirable.”
preload='metadata'
“Hints to the UA that the user is not expected to need the video, but that fetching its  metadata (dimensions, first frame, track list, duration, and so on) is desirable.”
preload='auto'
“Hints to the UA that optimistically downloading the entire video is considered desirable.”
preload or preload=''
The preload attribute is specified but no value is given. Specifying the empty string is the same as specifying “auto”.
```